# Como borrar un registro de una base de datos en php

Tags: php, mysql

Esta pregunta me eh mas compleja de explicarla de lo que parece..

```
<form action="" method="get">
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                          <th scope="col">Nom. Usuario</th>
                          <th scope="col">Borrar</th>
                          <th scope="col">Actualizar</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead> <div class="espacio"></div>
                      <tbody>
                    <?php  
                    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "gobbc");

                    $resultados = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM tbuser");
                    while($extraido = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)){
                      echo "
                        <tr>
                          <td>".$extraido['nombre'].'<br>'.$extraido['apellidoP'].'<br>'.$extraido['apellidoM']."</td>
                          <td>".$extraido['username']."</td>
                          <td><button name='Borrar' type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-md'><img src='img/papelera.png' width='25'></button></td>
                          <td><button name='Actualizar' type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-md'><img src='img/refrescar.png' width='21'></button></td>
                        </tr>";


                          if (isset($_POST['Borrar'])) {
                              mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM tbuser WHERE idUser=".$extraido['idUser']."");
                          }
                        }
                    ?>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </form>
```

Tengo una tabla donde aparecen todos los usuarios y un boton de borrar para cada fila y queria saber como hacer para que cuando le presione al boton se borre ese usuario de la base de datos

Comment: Bueno para empezar estaría mejor si poner por separado el codigo php y html por separado, empieza por crear un archivo de conexión, luego uno donde haras las eliminaciones, y ya en el form pon el atributo action="archivo donde se encuentra le codigo php y mysql para eliminar" y method="post"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aun que no te dare un resultado completo, espero que esta respuesta te ayude a comprender y solucionar tu problema.

Lo primero es tener encuenta que campo único vamos a eliminar el registro, lo mas adecuado si queremos eliminar un unico registro es utilizar la clave primaria de la tabla en tu ejemplo aparentemente es `idUser`.

Cuando creamos la tabla para el CRUD debemos crear un formulario por cada fila para el boton eliminar, el envio del formulario al pulsar el botón se recomienda que sea de tipo `DELETE` aun que podemos utilizar el verbo http `POST` para facilitar las cosas (o cualquier otro).

Por lo tanto tendríamos una tabla similar a la siguiente:

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
          <th scope="col">Nom. Usuario</th>
          <th scope="col">Borrar</th>
          <th scope="col">Actualizar</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
            <?php  
            $link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");
            $resultados = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM tbuser");

            while($extraido = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)){
            ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?= $extraido['nombre'] ?><br><?= $extraido['apellidoP'] ?><br><?= $extraido['apellidoM'] ?></td>
                  <td><?= $extraido['username'] ?></td>
                  <td>
                    <!-- AQUI CREAMOS EL FORM PARA ELIMINAR APUNTANDO AL ARCHIVO QUE HARA LA TAREA -->
                    <form method="POST" action="eliminar.php">
                        <!-- CREAMOS UN CAMPO OCULTO CON EL name idUser  y como value el id-->
                        <input type="hidden" name="idUser" value="<?= $extraido['idUser'] ?>">
                        <button name='Borrar' type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-md'><img src='img/papelera.png' width='25'></button>
                    </form>
                  </td>
                  <!-- PODRIAMOS HACER LO MISMO PARA EL BOTON ACTUALIZAR -->
                  <td><button name='Actualizar' type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-md'><img src='img/refrescar.png' width='21'></button></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

He comentado lo mas relevante en el codigo. Una vez hecho esto debemos crear el archivo que recibirá el `idUser` y que realizará la eliminación del registo en la base de datos en el ejemplo anterior es `eliminar.php` (definido en el action del formulario):

```
<?php

// recibimos el dato 
$idUser = $_POST['idUser'];

// ejecutamos la eliminacion
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "contraseña", "basedatos");
$resultados = mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM tbuser WHERE idUser=$idUser");

// redirigimos a la tabla
header( 'Location: http://url.es/formulario.php' );
```

> **ATENCIÓN** El **codigo expuesto es vulnerable a inyeccion SQL** y jamás debería ser utilizado tal cual en producción. Para más información al respecto revise: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Podrias ayudarme a como hacerle para que le presione al boton de actualizar y me escriba los datos de esa persona en el formulario, por favor

Comment: @JMM02 Similar a lo de eliminar, con un paso mas, rediriges a un archivo por ejemplo edit.php donde recuperas los datos del usuario de la base de datos y los muestras en un formulario donde poderlos editar, luego este formulario lo apuntas a otro archivo por ejemplo update.php y en el realizas el update a la base de datos. trata de realizarlo. Trata de realizarlo, si te atrancas en algo concreto crea una nueva pregunta indicando los errores o que es lo que no te funciona exactamente.